# Seagate Exos X14 ST14000NM0448 is not writing at all

Tags: linux, hard-drive

folks!
I have several Seagate Exos X14 model ST14000NM0448 disks in test environment in our company. But we can't use them because when I try to create FS on any of them with mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdX1 command it freezes forever with the fallowing output:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdd1
mke2fs 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
Filesystem label=
OS type: Linux
Block size=4096 (log=2)
Fragment size=4096 (log=2)
Stride=0 blocks, Stripe width=0 blocks
67108864 inodes, 268435456 blocks
13421772 blocks (5.00%) reserved for the super user
First data block=0
Maximum filesystem blocks=2415919104
8192 block groups
32768 blocks per group, 32768 fragments per group
8192 inodes per group
Superblock backups stored on blocks:
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208,
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968,
    102400000, 214990848

Allocating group tables: done
Writing inode tables: done
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: ^C^C^C
```

At the same time dmesg is full of errors (here is the compilation):

```
[1979096.654849] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1468008448
[1979096.654853] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 183500800, lost async page write
[1979097.161085] mpt3sas_cm0: log_info(0x31080000): originator(PL), code(0x08), sub_code(0x0000)
[1979097.271828] mpt3sas_cm0: log_info(0x31080000): originator(PL), code(0x08), sub_code(0x0000)
[1979097.382574] mpt3sas_cm0: log_info(0x31080000): originator(PL), code(0x08), sub_code(0x0000)
[1979097.382612] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_SOFT_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1979097.382616] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0a e8 01 00 00 00 01 00
[1979097.382619] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1463814144
[1979097.382622] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 182976512, lost async page write
[1979097.888750] mpt3sas_cm0: log_info(0x31080000): originator(PL), code(0x08), sub_code(0x0000)
[1979097.999495] mpt3sas_cm0: log_info(0x31080000): originator(PL), code(0x08), sub_code(0x0000)
[1979098.110236] mpt3sas_cm0: log_info(0x31080000): originator(PL), code(0x08), sub_code(0x0000)
[1979098.110275] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_SOFT_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1979098.110279] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0a f8 01 00 00 00 01 00
[1979098.110282] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1472202752
[1979102.636567] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1572866048
[1979102.636570] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 196608000, lost async page write
[1979103.142711] mpt3sas_cm0: log_info(0x31080000): originator(PL), code(0x08), sub_code(0x0000)
[1979103.253455] mpt3sas_cm0: log_info(0x31080000): originator(PL), code(0x08), sub_code(0x0000)
[1979103.253464] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[1979103.253468] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Aborted Command [current]
[1979103.253471] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[1979103.253474] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0b 20 01 00 00 00 01 00
[1979103.253476] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1493174272
[1979103.253479] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 186646528, lost async page write
[1979103.253497] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_SOFT_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1979103.253500] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0b 10 01 00 00 00 01 00
[1979103.253502] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1484785664
[1979107.535621] mpt3sas_cm0: log_info(0x31080000): originator(PL), code(0x08), sub_code(0x0000)
[1979107.535647] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_SOFT_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1979107.535650] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0b 80 01 00 00 00 01 00
[1979107.535652] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1543505920
[1979107.535654] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 192937984, lost async page write
[1979254.710800] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_SOFT_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1979254.710804] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 10 00 00 f0 00 00 10 00
[1979254.710807] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2147485568
[1979254.710810] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 268435440, lost async page write
[1979254.710816] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 268435441, lost async page write
[1979254.710819] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 268435442, lost async page write
[1979254.710822] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 268435443, lost async page write
[1979254.710825] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 268435444, lost async page write
[1979254.710827] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 268435445, lost async page write
[1979254.710830] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 268435446, lost async page write
[1979254.710833] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 268435447, lost async page write
[1979254.710836] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 268435448, lost async page write
[1979254.710838] Buffer I/O error on dev sdc1, logical block 268435449, lost async page write
[1979256.183201] mpt3sas_cm0: log_info(0x31080000): originator(PL), code(0x08), sub_code(0x0000)
[1979256.183245] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[1979256.183249] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Sense Key : Aborted Command [current]
[1979256.183252] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] Add. Sense: No additional sense information
[1979256.183256] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0e 18 01 00 00 00 01 00
[1979256.183258] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1891633152
[1979256.183279] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_SOFT_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[1979256.183282] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdc] CDB: Write(10) 2a 00 0f f8 01 00 00 00 01 00
[1979256.183284] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 2143291392
```

The SMART information:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST14000NM0448-2K8122
Serial Number:    xxxxxxxx
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0b441eabc
Firmware Version: SR03
User Capacity:    14,000,519,643,136 bytes [14.0 TB]
Sector Size:      4096 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   Unknown(0x0fe0) (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA >3.2 (0x1ff), 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Apr  3 18:17:05 2019
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
```

OS version: `CentOS7`, kernel version: 3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64.

Frankly speaking, after several hours of googling I sill have no clue. This is definitely not a motherboard/connection/interference problem as we have a couple of disks per machine on several machines and all of them behave the same.
Any ideas?

Comment: Did the drive record any errors? You did not post this information.

Comment: How I can check that?

Comment: Try the `-a` option to `smartctl`.

Answer (score 0):

ST14000NM0448 is a Host Managed SMR drive. That means the block device presented by the kernel will have several limitations.

Ext4 does not support HM-SMR drives. The only one that i know of currently is F2FS.

If you are programming your own application you can use [libzbc](https://github.com/hgst/libzbc) to work with it.

Comment: I've tried F2FS and was able to format the partiotion and then write some data, but after about 10 Gb device will fail until next remount.

Comment: I had the same experience.